# CASE expression returning NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case

I am trying to get status of my tickets using case expression. It's working perfectly but not returning `Not Available`. Rather than that it's returning a null value in Status as result.

What's wrong with this query?

Secondly can I make further if else on returning of operations?

```
Select 
Case 
      When Status=1 and isTaken=1 then 'Open'
      When Status=4 and isTaken=0 then 'Expire'
      When Status=2 and isTaken=0 then 'Pending'
      When Status=0 and isTaken=0 then 'Close'

Else 'Not Available' End As 'Status' 
from Tickets 
Where Id='1234567890'
```

Check Image for more explanation.

[image]

Comment: not quite right.. post `DDL` and `DML` and desired result. you can use `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com`  .. which sql version?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Sql Server 2012 Std

Comment: Your `case` expression *cannot* return `NULL`.  I think something is wrong with your interpretation of the results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what's wrong this query ?

Comment: @JaaZaib to answer your question to @Gordon the ONLY possible return values from this case statement are 'Open', 'Expire', 'Pending', 'Close', and 'Not Available' so it can't be the case statement causing your NULL.Hence the requests from others for your DDL/DML statements (`CREATE TABLE...`)

Comment: @Alan can you please check image attached

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you please check image attached

Comment: There simply isn't a row in the table with that id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not returning `NULL`, it's returning 0 rows. Your `WHERE` is filtering the rows or your table is empty.

Remove the `WHERE` and see if it returns rows, to see if the table isn't empty. If so then make sure that your `ID` filter is correct.

If your want to return a row even if the filter doesn't find anything then you need a `NOT EXISTS` or a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(20) = '1234567890'

SELECT
    F.ID,
    Case 
        When Status=1 and isTaken=1 then 'Open'
        When Status=4 and isTaken=0 then 'Expire'
        When Status=2 and isTaken=0 then 'Pending'
        When Status=0 and isTaken=0 then 'Close'
    Else 'Not Available' End As 'Status' 
FROM
    (VALUES (@ID)) AS F(ID)
    LEFT JOIN Tickets AS C ON F.ID = C.Id
```

Comment: Can you please modify query to return a row even if the filter doesn't exists

Comment: Thanks. Got my required result